# some problems with flex HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

I have a problem with flex HTTPService.In my application,I need to get some  resources from service by the way of flex HTTPService.And then,I need to use these resources in other place,since flex HTTPService is  asynchronous,so I don't know whether the resources are ready?And there are someone tell me how to deal whit it???

Comment: Way to little information to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of examples available for using the HTTPService object, but the short answer is:

1. Use data binding to the lastResult property of the HTTPService.
2. Implement the result event handler on the HTTPService to process the results when they're received.